# Get last 7 days best selling items? Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, widget, report, magento-1.9

I'm trying to find a way how to display the bestsellers items in Magento 1.9.

The widget is working correctly, but the issue is that it display's all time products.

What I'm looking for is to get the data from the last 7 day's and display the best sellers from that period of time.

Can someone help me with it? Or point me in the correct direction?

Thank you!

**Code update:**

```
    <?php class Bigdrop_ProductSlider_Block_Bestsellers extends Bigdrop_ProductSlider_Block_Slider_Abstract {
    protected $_code = 'bestsellers';

    /**
     * Retrieves sort by param
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getSortByParam()
    {
        return 'ordered_qty';
    }

    /**
     * Preparing product collection of the current Slider
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection|Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
     */
    protected function _prepareSliderCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty();

        if (Mage::helper('catalog/product_flat')->isEnabled()) {
            $collection->getSelect()
                ->joinInner(array(
                    'e2' => 'catalog_product_flat_' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
                ), 'e2.entity_id = e.entity_id');
        } else {
            $this->assignAttributes($collection);
        }

        $this->_applyStockVisibilityFilter($collection);
        $this->_setOrderToCollection($collection);
        $collection->getSelect()->limit($this->_getLimit());

        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: maybe you can post the code of the widget you're working on so we can better point out what is not working.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've added the code.

Answer (score 0):

If this items have `created_at`, or `bought_at` date field in collection you can filter it

`->addFieldToFilter(
   DATE_FIELD_NAME, 
   array(
      'from'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days')), 
      'to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   )
 )`

**Update**

You can replace

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                ->addOrderedQty();`

with

`$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
                                ->addFieldToFilter(
                                    'created_at', 
                                    array(
                                       'from'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days')), 
                                        'to' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                                    )
                                )->addOrderedQty();`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, could you please take a look at the code that I'm working with and tell me how to implement your suggestion correctly? Thank you

Comment: I've tryed the code, created_at and bought_at, with the bought_at the page brakes, with created_at the result's are the same as before? Any ideas? Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: You need to debug SQL query and see what it response to you in any MYSQL client. Code `die((string)$collection->getSelect());` return sql query on your page, copy and paste in any MYSQL client and see result